# Failure to run angular-spotify method in Ionic service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, spotify

I've been struggling with handling retrieval of Spotify data in an Ionic service all day, and something that was working earlier now suddenly doesn't.

I have my login script set up in a service, and it is all working fine. However, after the `console.log('updateInfo() called');` method inside `updateInfo`, the program will skip the rest of the function, avoiding gathering the data from Spotify.

This is the entire service so far:

```
.factory('SpotifyService', function ($cordovaOauth, Spotify) {

  var currentUser = {},
        userId = '';

    function login() {
        console.log('login() called');
        $cordovaOauth.spotify('583ac6ce144e4fcb9ae9c29bf9cad5ef', ['user-read-private', 'playlist-read-private']).then(function (result) {
            window.localStorage.setItem('spotify-token', result.access_token);
            Spotify.setAuthToken(result.access_token);
        }, function (error) {
          console.log("Error ->" + error);
        });
    }

    function updateInfo() {
        console.log('updateInfo() called');
         Spotify.getCurrentUser().then(function (data) {
            console.log('Gathering data');

            currentUser = data;
            userId = data.id;

            console.log("CURRENT USER: " + userId + " - (" + currentUser + ")");
            console.log('Done updating');
        });
    }

    return {
        getUser: function () {
            console.log('SpotifyService.getUser() called');
            var storedToken = window.localStorage.getItem('spotify-token');
            if (storedToken !== null) {
                console.log('Token accepted');
                currentUser = updateInfo();
                console.log('getUser function returns: ' + userId + " - (" + currentUser + ")");
                //currentUser = Spotify.getCurrentUser();
            } else {
                console.log('getUser else accessed');
                login();
            }
            return currentUser;
        }
    };
})
```

Any ideas as to why the `Spotify.getCurrentUser()` method won't run?

Comment: were you able to play Spotify track for more than 30 seconds ?

Comment: At the time, I was using Spotify's Web API which doesn't allow full track playback. There are methods outlined on their developer website that can help you set up a full Spotify player for authenticated users which requires native app code rather than a web app to run on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your issue is with promises. If `Spotify.getCurrentUser()` returns a promise you wouldn't know what the error is because you haven't defined a `catch` statement. You should read [Promises in Angular Explained as a Cartoon](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) for a simple and clear explanation of promises.

Revise your code to add a catch statement:

```
Spotify.getCurrentUser()
.then(function (data) {
    ...
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Massively helpful, thankyou. Turns out after being authenticated correctly for days, I'm obtaining the wrong access token from somewhere :/

Comment: :) Glad I could help. When I began using promises I ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use promises like $cordovaOauth.spotify() or Spotify.getCurrentUser() you have to define .catch block, that will help you debugging.

Add .catch block to the getCurrentUser() function call to track down your error and i would also recommend changing error callback pattern in auth function call into .catch block as well

```
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```